# Determine url for conditional statement

Tags: php

I am trying to add or remove class on one tag based on URL containing posts list with below condition

```
<?php
    if (($featured['featured']==true) AND (basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) != 'featured-questions'))
       return 'featured';
?>
```

Now this works fine if no pagination and url output is

```
http://example.com/featured-questions
```

I have added pagination now and url output from page 2 become as below

```
http://example.com/featured-questions
http://example.com/featured-questions?start=2
http://example.com/featured-questions?start=3
http://example.com/featured-questions?start=4
```

So how to determin this type of URL and apply conditionally class as I required?

Comment: Just check for $_GET['start']?

Comment: @slugonamission thanks for reply but can you please give me some idea how to do. I am beginner so need little detailed help.

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['start']))`

Comment: not working same output as mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi below solution works with my issue in case someone need the same.

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (($featured['featured']==true) AND (strpos($url,'featured-questions') == false) )
    return 'featured';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
    if (($featured['featured']==true) AND empty(strstr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'featured-questions')))
       return 'featured';
?>
```

Comment: Sorry to hear that. My idea was to look for 'featured-questions' as a substring of your url, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php. Maybe you will find something useful there.

Comment: I used strpos() and works wel and resolve my issue. Thanks for your help